# Pod moved to init state without restart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Getting into a strange scenario where, after 2-3 days pods of an application moves into `init state;` whereas none of its container has restarted.

`kubectl describe` of pod gives following status about its phases.

```
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True
```

As we can see all its containers are running and available but somehow, its init container started to execute again and gets stuck in some error. I checked for restart counts for individual container and it is 0. This is not one off scenario, this is reproducible every 2-3 days. I also looked at RAM and CPU spikes and nothing there.

In which scenario can this issue happen? What could trigger execution of init container without any restart or without failure of its containers.

Comment: found similar issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67261?fbclid=IwAR04De0mvU9lTs0E9VlOqivXCnSRKBCiarcEVE_q6SGXErnlYCtdWJPsgvU

Comment: What is your version of kubernetes ? Is it on-prem installation e.g. set up with kubeadm, minikube ?

Comment: it is on-prem installation.

Comment: Kubeadm ? Minikube ? Or maybe a cluster build from scratch, so called "the hard way" ? What version of kubernetes do you use ?

Comment: k8s version 1.15.3 and definately its not minikube. they have some product which deploys k8s for DEV teams.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, it was an housekeeping script that was doing

```
docker system prune -a
```

and it was deleting all untagged containers. It also included our init container, may be because it was completed/stopped. I will recommend to use kubernetes GC rather than executing these low level commands in cluster.

Comment: Great that you managed to find the cause of the issue. How did you get to this ? You're right, better not to tinker too much at docker level, when using kubernetes.

Comment: @mario, first I looked at `kubectl describe` of this pod (noticed time when this issue occurred) and then logged on to worker node on which this pod was scheduled. Now I started to look at events and involved one of administrators of this cluster. We found that they had a cron job running weekly at that time. We replicated that step and now we know what caused issue.